# Bash scripts and file conflicts

Tags: bash, scripts

and thanks in advance for any advice.

I'm having trouble finding an answer to my question elsewhere. I've been working on a script that will watch a directory, and then move files to various other directories based on certain criteria. Here's what I've got so far:

```
cd `dirname $0`/watch
  while true
  do
    inotifywait -e moved_to ../watch --format "%f" | while read FILE
    do
      if $(echo "$FILE" | grep -q ".jpg"); then
          cp "./$FILE" "../images/"
      elif $(echo "$FILE" | grep -q ".mp4"); then
          cp "./$FILE" "../videos/"
      elif $(echo "$FILE" | grep -q ".mp3"); then
          cp "./$FILE" "../audio/"
      else
          cp "./$FILE" "../other/"
    fi
    done
  done
```

This script works as it should if one file at a time is moved into ./watch, but if multiple files are moved, only the first of them gets moved from ./watch to the corresponding directory. Here's another idea I have, but am unsure how this would handle problems such as trying to sort/move incomplete files:

```
while true
do
inotifywait -e moved_to `dirname $0`/watch && /bin/bash `dirname $0`/autotorrent.sh
done
```

which will launch the following script when files are added:

```
cd `dirname $0`/watch
for i in *; do
    if $(echo "$FILE" | grep -q ".jpg"); then
        cp "./$FILE" "../images/"
    elif $(echo "$FILE" | grep -q ".mp4"); then
        cp "./$FILE" "../videos/"
    elif $(echo "$FILE" | grep -q ".mp3"); then
        cp "./$FILE" "../audio/"
    else
        cp "./$FILE" "../other/"
    fi
done
```

I'm just not sure how best to handle moving multiple files which may or may not take considerable time to copy. I've got several ideas, but none of them really seem to be the robust solution I'm looking for.

Thanks again to anyone who has some advice for me

Comment: Quick suggestion: your `grep` commands really should be `grep -qF ".mp4"` or, even better, `grep -q '\.mp4$'` etc. The dot in regular expressions matches any character, so you *really* should escape it to make it literal. Otherwise e.g. stuff like `foobarmp4` will be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Since your files could be Large, the `cp` takes non-zero time. During this time, you probably miss notifications. Try tossing all the `cp` commands into the background by appending a `&` to each. That will get you back to the `inotifywait` quicker.

Also, you could eliminate a bunch of calls to `grep` by doing:

```
    j=${i##*.}
    case "$j" in 
        jpg) cp $i ../images/ & ;;
        mp4) cp $i ../videos/ & ;;
        mp3) cp $i ../audio/ & ;;
        *) cp $i ../other/& ;;
    esac
```

Although I don't see why you want to keep a copy of each file both directories, why not use `mv` instead of `cp`?

@zpawwn: On further `man inotifywait` reading, I found `--monitor`, so, your script should be:

```
cd `dirname $0`/watch
inotifywait -e moved_to ../watch --format "%f" --monitor | while read FILE
do
    j="${FILE##*.}"
        case "$j" in 
            jpg) mv "$FILE" ../images/ & ;;
            mp4) mv "$FILE" ../videos/ & ;;
            mp3) mv "$FILE" ../audio/ & ;;
            *) mv "$FILE" ../other/& ;;
        esac
 done
```

Let `inotifywait` manage the file event queueing, and spit out filenames as it notices them. The old way had `inotifywait` finding ONE new file and exiting, letting your `cp` stuff run, then restart watching. The other files (that arrived at the same time) are no longer new (they were there when the 2nd `inotifywait` started).

Comment: I like that method for eliminating the grep calls. I also had forgotten to change the cp commands to mv when posting - that was actually something I had changed just for testing the script, and plan to use mv once everything is working properly

Comment: I have modified the code to work pretty much exactly how you illustrated it here, the main difference is right now i've replaced the cp commands inside of the case statement with an echo "SUCCESS" message, and I'm getting inconsistent behavior. If I copy over a directory of 13 files, I get anywhere from 1 to 13 "SUCCESS" lines printed

Comment: Eliminate the outer `while true` loop, read `man inotifywait` and use the `--monitor` switch. What you're doing is inefficient.